# Link individual podcast pages from the main page

Tags: support, blog

Normally, new podcasts would be featured in the yellowish box in the right sidebar, and it probably still will this time, but I'm not *that* patient. Anyway, I saw [the tweet](https://twitter.com/StackPodcast/status/808394747286982656) saying it was live. Unfortunately, the link was directly to the soundcloud page, and I always like the description. So I headed to the blog, and then to the [podcast-part of the blog](https://stackoverflow.com/podcast), where I found that posts seem to have no single link or reference to the podcast page ([like this one](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/Stack-Overflow-Podcast-93-A-Very-Spolsky-Halloween-Special/)), despite its blue colour. Only, again, the soundcloud link. I really don't want to reverse-engineer its URL (although there are tools on [PCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102812/53513)). Where can I find these links?

**TL;DR**
Posts on the [podcast-part of the blog](https://stackoverflow.com/podcast) don't link to the individual post pages.

Comment: I always end up clicking on the "Company" section, instead, to avoid this issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try at [the blog.](http://stackoverflow.blog/company/podcasts/) Your link to the "blog" is not actually to the blog- It's a Stack Overflow link to a list of the podcasts.

A way to get there is to navigate to any other blog post. In the top right corner, click "All Posts".

> [image: All Posts Link]

Otherwise, use the "Podcasts" link from one of the category pages or the main company blog section (at `http://stackoverflow.blog/company/`) or navigate directly to the url at `http://stackoverflow.blog/company/podcasts/`.

> [image: Podcasts Link]

Now, the newest podcast isn't listed there. This is likely because *there isn't a blog post for it yet.* The podcast is recorded and out there, but they may not have the blog post written for this particular podcast yet.

Once there's an actual post for it, it should show up on the blog site.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, sorry about that. Corrected the relevant line.